# How to resolve error: collectstatic - Could not find backend 'storages.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a django app and I have installed the module: `django-storages[azure]` with the command: `pipenv install django-storages[azure]`

And now I try to run the collectstatic command. But if I enter the command: `python manage.py collectstatic`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\handler.py", line 52, in create_storage
    storage_cls = import_string(backend)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages.custom_azure'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\repos\django_upload\myuploader\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\repos\django_upload\myuploader\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 184, in handle   
    if self.is_local_storage() and self.storage.location:
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 245, in is_local_storage
    return isinstance(self.storage, FileSystemStorage)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 280, in __getattribute__
    value = super().__getattribute__(name)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 251, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 540, in _setup
    self._wrapped = storages[STATICFILES_STORAGE_ALIAS]
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\handler.py", line 43, in __getitem__
    storage = self.create_storage(params)
  File "C:\Users\engel\.virtualenvs\django_upload-sYcQHG5j\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\handler.py", line 54, in create_storage
    raise InvalidStorageError(f"Could not find backend {backend!r}: {e}") from e
django.core.files.storage.handler.InvalidStorageError: Could not find backend 'storages.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage': No module named 'storages.custom_azure'PS C
```

So my pipfile looks:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"
django-storages = {extras = ["azure"], version = "*"}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```

settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "uploader",
    "storages"
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'uploader.custom_azure.AzureMediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'
STATIC_LOCATION = "static"
MEDIA_LOCATION = "media"
AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "name"
AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
```

and I have a file custom.azure.py in the app uploader:

```
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage

class AzureMediaStorage(AzureStorage):   
    account_name = ''name'
    # Must be replaced by your <storage_account_key>
    account_key= 'key'
    azure_container = 'media'
    expiration_secs = None


class AzureStaticStorage(AzureStorage):   
    account_name = 'name'   
    account_key = 'key'
    azure_container = 'static'
    expiration_secs = None
```

Question: how to resolve the error: `Could not find backend 'storages.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage': No module named 'storages.custom_azure'`

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback

Comment: Also what's your Django version

Comment: Where is your custom code placed? What's the file location & filename?

Comment: I would assume you have to change your `STATICFILES_STORAGE= "<YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDERNAME>.uploader.<FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION>.AzureStaticStorage"`

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I was able to collect static files without any errors [image](https://i.imgur.com/2G5mcKr.png). I have Python version 3.12 and Django version 5.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM. My directory looks like: PS C:\repos\django_upload\myuploader>. I am not in the virtual directory

Comment: But I can run the application with python manage.py runserver

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Django version 5.0.1, using settings 'myuploader.settings'

Comment: But I can run the application with python manage.py runserver. But that doesn't matter isn't? I have a pip file and a pipfile.lock file

Comment: @DasariKamali. But I see in your image django-storage. And I have pipenv install django-storages[azure]

Comment: @mightycodeNewton I can install the static files without virtual environment also.

Comment: @DasariKamali. Can you show me then? You also have the custom.azure.py file? and how does your settings.py file look like?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Yes, see in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/ev9LOaH.png), I installed static files without virtual environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256552/discussion-between-dasari-kamali-and-mightycode-newton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, solved:

`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'`

and I removed this:

`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'`